# Does UIImage's -imageNamed: method work for image files stored in 'Documents'?

Tags: iphone, uikit, uiimage, documents

My app downloads a small image file from a remote server and I am trying to display it along with some other small image files that are pre-installed in the app. I am using [UIImage imageNamed:@"TheImageName.png"] to get the images (see below for more detail). The pre-installed images display as expected but the image in my apps 'Documents' directory is no where to be found. Should I be using -imageNamed for an image in 'Documents' or some other method?

```
UIImage* documentsImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TheImageName.png"];
UIImageView* anImageView = [[UIimageView alloc] initWithImage:documentsImage];
[self.view addSubview:anImageView];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, nevermind. I found that using [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath] works for this. imageNamed just returns nil.

Comment: Yup, notice that imageNamed: doesn't only loads the image, it also caches it in memory. While imageWithContentsOfFile: doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

No, `+imageNamed:` only loads images from the app bundle.

Also, don't include the `.png` extension when using that class method.

Comment: More specifically, "On iOS 4 and later, if the file is in PNG format, it is not necessary to specify the .PNG filename extension. Prior to iOS 4, you must specify the filename extension." -- http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageNamed: